# Replace t1 col with t2 col when [condition] + different datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this situation: `deceduti(sigla,denominazione_provincia)` , `province(sigla_provincia,denominazione_provincia)`
where `sigla` is a NUMBER and `sigla_provincia` is a CHAR(2).

I want to set `deceduti.sigla=province.sigla_provincia` where `deceduti.denominazione_provincia=province.denominazione_provincia`.

I have tried different ways but no one worked. I'd appreciate to understand how can i do this with join operator. There are my tries:

```
MERGE INTO DECEDUTI                 -- error with the datatypes
USING PROVINCE
ON ( DECEDUTI.DENOMINAZIONE_PROVINCIA = PROVINCE.DENOMINAZIONE_PROVINCIA )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET DECEDUTI.Sigla = PROVINCE.sigla_provincia;
```

/

```
UPDATE                              -- oracle doesnt have the on update+policy react
(SELECT DECEDUTI.Sigla as OLD, to_number(PROVINCE.Sigla_provincia) as NEW
FROM DECEDUTI
INNER JOIN PROVINCE
ON DECEDUTI.DENOMINAZIONE_PROVINCIA = PROVINCE. DENOMINAZIONE_PROVINCIA
) t
SET t.OLD = t.NEW
```

/

```
UPDATE deceduti T
   SET T.sigla =
     (SELECT distinct sigla_provincia
     FROM PROVINCE A
     WHERE A.denominazione_provincia = T.denominazione_provincia);
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code, never. Paste it in the question and format it using four space of indentation, the Ctrl+K keyboard shortcut or the "{}" button

Comment: The names in your queries don't match your schema description.

Comment: ok sorry, i'll edit it. Anyway why? I just wanted to make it more clear

Comment: Because: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @DomenicoPalladino . . . Sample data and desired results would make it easier to understand what you want to accomplish.  Also what does it mean that they don't work?  Is there an error or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have:

```
create table deceduti
  (sigla                    number,
   denominazione_provincia  unknown_datatype
  );

create table province
  (sigla_provincia          char(2),
   denominazione_provincia  unknown_datatype
  );
```

Data stored within looks like this (according to datatypes you mentioned):

```
DECEDUTI:
sigla             denominazione_provincia
-----             -----------------------
25                1000
null              2000

PROVINCE:
sigla_provincia   denominazione_provincia
---------------   -----------------------
AB                1000
X1                2000
```

As tables are joined on `denominazione_provincia`, you'd like to - for its value = `1000` - put `AB` into the `deceduti.sigla` column. How do you plan to put `AB` into a `NUMBER` datatype column? That won't work.

The simplest option is to

```
alter table deceduti modify sigla (char(2));
```

but only if `sigla` column is empty; shouldn't be problem to set it to `NULL` as it is supposed to accept a new value anyway. If you want to keep some "old" values, then it gets more complicated (creating a new column, store current `sigla` value in there, empty `sigla`, change its datatype, move data back, drop new column).

Other options are more complicated, e.g.

- make sure that all `sigla_provincia` values are numeric so that `to_number(sigla_provincia)` returns a number
- update `deceduti.sigla` values only for `denominazione_provincia`s whose *pair* in `province` contains number in `sigla_provincia`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
I want the sigla col as a CHAR(2). I'd like to literally take all the records in sigla_provincia and paste them into sigla replacing his values.
The simplest solution is great but i should drop, alter and then update the col. 
It would be great to find the right method to do this in a oneshot.

Comment: `varchar2(2)`, surely?

Comment: I told you *how*, Domenico. Read from "creating a new column, store current ...".